# Using (click) event in one html template to control [hidden] element in a separate template Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular

I have 2 TypeScript files, both with HTML templates in the @Component. Let's say one template displays info cards that can be collapsed or expanded with `[hidden]="collapsed"`. This function exists in either file:

```
    public collapsed : boolean = false;
    toggleCollapsed(){
    this.collapsed = !this.collapsed;
    }
```

Then in a separate template I have a button to trigger this event

```
    <button clear (click)="toggleCollapsed()">
      <ion-icon name="expand"></ion-icon>
      Expand All
    </button>
```

Basically the button and info cards are in different templates/files but displayed on the same page in the view. I need help with making the button expand/collapse the info cards even though they're in separate templates. 
I figured this topic is general enough to help others as well if answered :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just short sample:

```
<panel #panel>
<button (click)="panel.collapsed=!panel.collapsed">
```

Create component reference `#panel` and use it to change state.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the relationship (if any) between the two components.  If there is a parent-child relationship, you can use an input property or an event (depending on which direction the communication needs to flow).

If there is no relationship, use a service with a Subject.  One component will `subscribe()` to the Subject in order to listen for events, and the other will generate events via the Subject.

The [Component Interaction Cookbook](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service) has examples of all three.